# How many grams is "1 can" of beans?

Tags: beans, measurements

There is a recipe for [bean burgers](https://www.thecheaplazyvegan.com/15-minute-weeknight-vegan-dinner-recipes-for-a-stress-free-evening/) which I am trying to make.

The recipe calls for 1 can of beans.

First of all, bean cans are typically measured in milliliters.

Second of all, they come in various sizes.

For instance
[398 ml can](https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca/organic-black-beans/p/20300173003_EA),
[540 ml can](https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca/black-beans/p/20313447006_EA)

I know that I should not use the liquid from the can, but how many grams of drained beans should I use?

Comment: In the US a "can" of many things is about 15oz. There are smaller and bigger cans but I always go with a 15oz can when a recipe calls for a "can" of something.

Comment: @SteveChambers So, I should use 425 grams of beans?

Comment: @user3503704 no because that includes the liquid (a 15 Oz tin of tomatoes is all tomato, the same size tin has 15 Oz of beans+water)

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, a 400 gram can of beans contains about 240 grams of drained beans. That will vary slightly by the type of bean.

Answer (score 1):

It's not what I would call a well-written recipe.  Also, a slight variation in the amount of beans will probably not be a big deal for the final prouct.  However, given the information you provide, I would suggest that in this case a "can" refers to your 398ml can. Use them all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Rose](https://www.thecheaplazyvegan.com/about/) from Cheap Lazy Vegan is Canadian and living (or at least lived in 2015) in the UK. Since the recipe does not state what type of beans, I would assume that if she is in North America she would be using either black beans or kidney beans. The Goya brand usually sells their [beans](https://www.target.com/p/goya-black-beans-15-5oz/-/A-14771988#lnk=sametab) at a net weight of 439 grams. If she is in the UK and using baked beans, most likely she would be using [Heinz Beanz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001QTN58S) which would be 415 grams net weight. Both of these weights would include the sauce.

Since your can would either be a bit smaller or a bit larger than these standard sizes, I would recommend following the recipe and then adding the oat flour as you go. You may need to add more or less oat flour to get to the patty consistency.

Comment: I'm sure it's not baked beans - that would specify with sauce or washed.  Tinned kidney beans are very common in the UK, black beans less so but there are other common varieties

Comment: That's a good point about the baked beans. Given the limited info, I'm mostly trying to hypothesize what is available to the recipe's author and work backwards.

Comment: I can see that point of view. They look like red kidney beans in the photo, I think.  To my mind the recipes are perfectly reasonable as outline recipes for those more willing to apply trial and error than to wade through extraneous text, but they're neither detailed nor foolproof.  My own beanburgers are even cheaper but not so lazy, starting with slow cooking mixed dried beans with onion etc.